# Photoswipe opening gallery in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, photoswipe

So im working with Jquery Mobile and photoswipe to create a small image gallery for a portfolio but once I place the call for photoswipe, it opens the gallery right away in the browser. Its not the default call from the photoswipe website because it just doesn't work.

heres my code.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0;" name="viewport" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.structure.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.theme.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-mobile/photoswipe.css">



    <script type-"text/javascript" src="jquery-mobile/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type-"text/javascript" src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-mobile/klass.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-mobile/code.photoswipe.jquery-3.0.5.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        (function(window, $, PhotoSwipe)
        {
            $(document).ready(function()
            {
                $("#gallery a").photoSwipe(
                {
                    enableMouseWheel: false,
                    enableKeyboard: false
                });

                $("#gallery a:first").click();
            });
        }(window, window.jQuery, window.Code.PhotoSwipe));

    </script>

</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
    <h1>welcome</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="gallery">


            <a href="web/full/photo1.jpg" rel="external"><img src="web/thumb/photo1thumb.jpg" alt="Image 001" /></a>
            <a href="web/full/photo2.jpg" rel="external"><img src="web/thumb/photo2thumb.jpg" alt="Image 002" /></a>
            <a href="web/full/photo3.jpg" rel="external"><img src="web/thumb/photo3thumb.jpg" alt="Image 003" /></a>
            <a href="web/full/photo4.jpg" rel="external"><img src="web/thumb/photo4thumb.jpg" alt="Image 004" /></a>
            <a href="web/full/photo5.jpg" rel="external"><img src="web/thumb/photo5thumb.jpg" alt="Image 005" /></a>
            <a href="web/full/photo6.jpg" rel="external"><img src="web/thumb/photo6thumb.jpg" alt="Image 006" /></a>


    </div>

    <div data-role="footer">
    <h2>2012</h2>
    </div>
</div>  

</body>
</html>
```

Any idea on what i should do?

Answer (score 0):

try removing

```
$("#gallery a:first").click();
```

I think this is calling the gallery after you init with call to `$("#gallery a").photoSwipe`

Comment: Great, everything works well. I'm just not sure why the default call doesnt work? Here's the call


$(document).ready(function(){

 var myPhotoSwipe = $("#Gallery a").photoSwipe({ enableMouseWheel: false , enableKeyboard: false });